# Deleting Sub elements in a xml tree based on given attribute list

Tags: python, xml, recursion

I am trying to take in a csv file and remove some elements based upon their attributes. The code I have is currently working to remove elements based upon the list but will not remove elements back to back, likely because im messing with elements while iterating over them. Haven't been able to find a work around, any ideas?

```
def attri_remover(tree, remove_list):
    root = tree
    return_tree = tree
    for child in root:
        if child.attrib in remove_list:
            return_tree.remove(child)
        elif len(child) >= 1:
            child = attri_remover(child, remove_list)

    return return_tree
```

For example, if given csv:

```
<RECORDS>
  <RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="sort">
      <PVAL>40342</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="prod_number">
      <PVAL>94201</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="prod_availabile">
      <PVAL>42810932-1</PVAL>
    </PROP>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="sort">
      <PVAL>94829</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="prod_number">
      <PVAL>83921</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="prod_availabile">
      <PVAL>43901223-1</PVAL>
    </PROP>
  </RECORD>
</RECORDS>
```

I convert that into an element tree
And given remove list:

```
[{'NAME': 'prod_available'}]
```

The function should return an element tree that equates to:

```
<RECORDS>
  <RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="sort">
      <PVAL>40342</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="prod_number">
      <PVAL>94201</PVAL>
    </PROP>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="sort">
      <PVAL>94829</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="prod_number">
      <PVAL>83921</PVAL>
    </PROP>
  </RECORD>
</RECORDS>
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the csv, xml input, and desired output? Also, are you using ElementTree, lxml, or something else?

Comment: @DanielHaley I have updated edited the post with the requested information. Thank you.

Comment: Read about [incremental-event-parsing - Section:Modifying the tree](https://lxml.de/parsing.html#incremental-event-parsing)

Comment: @DanielHaley Yes it did. Sorry for the delay in accepting it. got pulled onto some workstuff and couldn't loop around for awhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to select the element to delete with XPath instead of iterating over all elements.

You didn't specify if you were using ElementTree or lxml (or something else entirely) so I chose [lxml](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) because [XPath support in ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) is limited.

Here's an example...

**XML Input** (input.xml)

```xml
<RECORDS>
  <RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="sort">
      <PVAL>40342</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="prod_number">
      <PVAL>94201</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="prod_available">
      <PVAL>42810932-1</PVAL>
    </PROP>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="sort">
      <PVAL>94829</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="prod_number">
      <PVAL>83921</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="prod_available">
      <PVAL>43901223-1</PVAL>
    </PROP>
  </RECORD>
</RECORDS>
```

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree


def attri_remover(input_tree, remove_list):
    for attr_name, attr_value in [(k, v) for attr in remove_list for (k, v) in attr.items()]:
        # XPath matches any element that contains an attribute with the same name and value.
        for target_element in input_tree.xpath(f"//*[@{attr_name}[.='{attr_value}']]"):
            target_element.getparent().remove(target_element)


tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

# Appears to be a list of dicts that contain attribute name/value pairs.
to_remove = [{'NAME': 'prod_available'}]

attri_remover(tree, to_remove)

tree.write("output.xml")
```

**XML Output** (output.xml)

```xml
<RECORDS>
  <RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="sort">
      <PVAL>40342</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="prod_number">
      <PVAL>94201</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="sort">
      <PVAL>94829</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="prod_number">
      <PVAL>83921</PVAL>
    </PROP>
    </RECORD>
</RECORDS>
```

Note: The function in my example modifies the original tree. If you want your function to return a different tree, you should make a copy of the tree, modify it, then return it.